# How to use sklearn TFIdfVectorizer on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I am working with a tab separated file that looks like this:

```
0   abch7619    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 42Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat…..........
1   uewl0928    Duis aute irure d21olor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excep3teur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
0   ahwb3612    Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus  error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem                            quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur
1   llll2019    adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et                                     dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur???? Quis autem                                                                               vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
0   jdne2319    At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. 
1   asbq0918    Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio................................ Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et               aut
```

My goal is to produce a  dataframe that looks like this:

```
classification  ID  word1   word2   word3   word4
foo foo foo foo foo foo
```

Where ech word in the long text field of the TSV appears as a feature (column), and its value is the words TFIDF.

I could try and go about this manually, but I am looking to use [`sklearn's TFIDFVECTORIZER`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) to produce this. However, I need to preprocess the text in the field, to follow certain guidelines.

So far, I can read in the `.tsv` file, create the dataframe, and preprocess the text. What I am having trouble doing is combining my text formatting functions to then pass it to the `TFIDFVECTORIZER`

Below is what I have:

```
import nltk, string, csv, operator, re, collections, sys, struct, zlib, ast, io, math, time
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize, RegexpTokenizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from collections import defaultdict, Counter
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from math import sqrt
from itertools import islice
import pandas as pd

# This function removes numbers from an array
def remove_nums(arr): 
    # Declare a regular expression
    pattern = '[0-9]'  
    # Remove the pattern, which is a number
    arr = [re.sub(pattern, '', i) for i in arr]    
    # Return the array with numbers removed
    return arr

# This function cleans the passed in paragraph and parses it
def get_words(para):   
    # Create a set of stop words
    stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
    # Split it into lower case    
    lower = para.lower().split()
    # Remove punctuation
    no_punctuation = (nopunc.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)) for nopunc in lower)
    # Remove integers
    no_integers = remove_nums(no_punctuation)
    # Remove stop words
    dirty_tokens = (data for data in no_integers if data not in stop_words)
    # Ensure it is not empty
    tokens = [data for data in dirty_tokens if data.strip()]
    # Ensure there is more than 1 character to make up the word
    tokens = [data for data in tokens if len(data) > 1]

    # Return the tokens
    return tokens 

def main():

    tsv_file = "filepath"
    print(tsv_file)
    csv_table=pd.read_csv(tsv_file, sep='\t')
    csv_table.columns = ['rating', 'ID', 'text']

    s = pd.Series(csv_table['text'])
    new = s.str.cat(sep=' ')
    vocab = get_words(new)
    print(vocab)

main()
```

Which produces:

```
['decent', 'terribly', 'inconsistent', 'food', 'ive', 'great', 'dishes', 'terrible', 'ones', 'love', 'chaat', 'times', 'great', 'fried', 'greasy', 'mess', 'bad', 'way', 'good', 'way', 'usually', 'matar', 'paneer', 'great', 'oversalted', 'peas', 'plain', 'bad', 'dont', 'know', 'coinflip', 'good', 'food', 'oversalted', 'overcooked', 'bowl', 'either', 'way', 'portions', 'generous', 'looks', 'arent', 'everything', 'little', 'divito', 'looks', 'little', 'scary', 'looking', 'like', 'ive', 'said', 'cant', 'judge', 'book', 'cover', 'necessarily', 'kind', 'place', 'take', 'date', 'unless', 'shes', 'blind', 'hungry', 'man', 'oh', 'man', 'food', 'ever', 'good', 'ordered', 'breakfast', 'lunch', 'dinner', 'fantastico', 'make', 'homemade', 'corn', 'tortillas', 'several', 'salsas', 'breakfast', 'burritos', 'world', 'cost', 'mcdonalds', 'meal', 'family', 'eats', 'frequently', 'frankly', 'tired',
```

However, I am not sure if this is the proper format to allow `TFIDFVECTORIZER` to work right.  When I try to use it, I used below code which ran properly:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer()
feature_matrix = tfidf.fit_transform(csv_table['text'])
df = pd.DataFrame(data=feature_matrix.todense(), columns=tfidf.get_feature_names())
print(df)
```

But simply gave me results like:

```
  (0, 4147)     0.09801030349526582
  (0, 4482)     0.11236176486916101
  (0, 6304)     0.13511683683910816
  :     :
  (1998, 11298) 0.08469000607646575
  (1998, 500)   0.10185473904595721
  (1998, 3196)  0.07801251063240894
```

And I don't know what I am looking at there. How can I use TFIDFVECTORIZER to accomplish my goal of creating a feature matrix of each word (after my cleaning logic has been applied) with TFIDF values?

Comment: I believe you need to convert feature_matrix to dense

Comment: What does that mean? @DanielMesejo

Comment: The output is a sparse matrix, a sparse matrix saves space in memory by not representing the values that are zero, so you need to convert it to dense

Comment: I changed to dense, same output @DanielMesejo

Comment: In your example you are printing feature matrix, print df, todense does not change feature_matrix it returns a new matrix

Comment: I guess that seems to be working, except many terms are terms I want to exclude via my cleaning procedure, but I still don't know how to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of fit_transform is a sparse matrix, so you need to convert it to dense form, and to include your cleaning steps you could try:

```
s = pd.Series(csv_table['text'])
corpus = s.apply(lambda s: ' '.join(get_words(s)))

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)

df = pd.DataFrame(data=X.todense(), columns=vectorizer.get_feature_names())
print(df)
```

Basically what you need to do is apply your *cleaning procedure* (`get_words`) for each document in `csv_table['text']` (element in `s`) before passing it to `fit_transform`.

Comment: I've read the same example. How does that work with _my_ data, where my `corpus` is a dataframe field? Additionally, how can I build in my cleaning steps?

Comment: That makes a lot of sense now. I appreciate the explanation and not just code.

Comment: Glad I could help @JerryM.