# why smote raise "Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples"?

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, text-classification, countvectorizer

I try to classify emotion from tweet with dataset of 4401 tweet, when i use smaller sample of data (around 15 tweet) everything just work fine, but when i use the full dataset it raise the error of

```
Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [7, 3520]
```

the error happen when i try to oversampling the data using smote after transforming the data using countvectorizer.

**This is the code where the error raise**

```
# N-gram Feature and Term Frequency
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,3))
x_train_tf = vectorizer.fit_transform(str(x_train).split('\n')).toarray()
x_test_tf = vectorizer.transform(str(x_test).split('\n')).toarray()
df_output = pd.DataFrame(data =x_train_tf, columns = vectorizer.get_feature_names_out())
display(df_output)
# the print shape is (7 rows × 250 columns)

smote = SMOTE(random_state=42, k_neighbors=5)
x_smote, y_smote = smote.fit_resample(x_train_tf, y_train)
print("Total Train Data SMOTE : ",x_smote.shape), print("Total Train Label SMOTE : ",y_smote)
```

i did not understand why this is happening so some explanation could really help.
i already tried to solve it using answers from other similiar question but nothing have worked.

**This is the full code**

```
import nltk
import re
#nltk.download()
import string
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from nltk import everygrams
from collections import Counter
from sklearn import preprocessing
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from Sastrawi.Stemmer.StemmerFactory import StemmerFactory
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, recall_score, precision_score, f1_score, confusion_matrix

dataset = pd.read_csv("G:/TA/Program/dataset/Twitter_Emotion_Dataset.csv", encoding='latin-1')
# Preprocessing
dataset['case_folding_tweet'] = dataset['tweet'].str.casefold()
dataset['only_alphabet_tweet'] = [re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]+\s*', ' ', s) for s in dataset['case_folding_tweet']]
dataset['data_cleaning_tweet'] = dataset['only_alphabet_tweet'].str.replace(r'\b\w{1}\b','').str.replace(r'\s+', ' ')

slangword_dictionary = ("G:/TA/Program/dataset/kamus_singkatan.csv")

deslang = {}
list_slangword = open(slangword_dictionary).readlines()
for line in list_slangword:
    slang, unslang = line.strip().split(';')
    deslang[slang] = unslang
deslang[slang] = {r"\b{}\b".format(k): v for k, v in deslang.items()}

dataset['data_cleaning_tweet'] = dataset['data_cleaning_tweet'].replace(deslang[slang], regex=True)
dataset['convert_slang_tweet'] = dataset['data_cleaning_tweet']

replace_dictionary = {'tidak ': 'tidak', 'bukan ': 'bukan', 'jangan ': 'jangan', 'belum ': 'belum'}
dataset['convert_negation_tweet'] = dataset['convert_slang_tweet'].replace(replace_dictionary, regex=True)
dataset['tokenization_tweet'] = dataset['convert_negation_tweet'].apply(word_tokenize) 
list_stopwords = set(stopwords.words("indonesian"))
list_stopwords.add('username')
list_stopwords.add('url')
dataset['stopword_removal_tweet'] = dataset['tokenization_tweet'].apply(lambda x: [item for item in x if item not in list_stopwords])

factory = StemmerFactory()
stemmer = factory.create_stemmer()
dataset['stemmed_tweet'] = dataset['stopword_removal_tweet'].apply(lambda x: [stemmer.stem(y) for y in x]) 

# Split data
x = dataset["stemmed_tweet"].values
y = dataset["label"].values
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, train_size=0.8, random_state= 42)

# Get N-gram and TF
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,3))
x_train_tf = vectorizer.fit_transform(str(x_train).split('\n')).toarray()
x_test_tf = vectorizer.transform(str(x_test).split('\n')).toarray()

# Oversampling
smote = SMOTE(random_state=42, k_neighbors=5)
x_smote, y_smote = smote.fit_resample(x_train_tf, y_train)

print("Total Train Data SMOTE : ",x_smote.shape), print("Total Train Label SMOTE : ",y_smote)

gnb_classifier = GaussianNB()
gnb_classifier.fit(x_smote, y_smote)
print(gnb_classifier)
y_pred = gnb_classifier.predict(x_test_tf)
print("Emotion Predicted :", y_pred)
```

[Link to the dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15JAhVWTSU0oS3zQXdEBT89KOV6dr9Zns/view?usp=share_link)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fix the problem using the answer from this post [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58477381/19640802)
by joining all the train data column before vectorizing.

```
df_train = pd.DataFrame(data=x_train)
df_test = pd.DataFrame(data=x_test)

series = pd.Series(df_train['stemmed_tweet'])
corpus = series.apply(lambda series: ' '.join(series))
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,3), lowercase=False)
x_train_tf = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus).toarray()
x_test_tf = vectorizer.transform(str(df_test.values).split("\n")).toarray()
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot solve it precisely because I don't have your data, but here are a few observations which should help:

- apparently `x_train_tf` has only 7 rows? it's not enough for training a model and it's not 80% of 4401, as you're supposed to obtain from `train_test_split`.
- Note that `y_train` has 3520 rows = 4401 * 80%, the correct number of rows.

I suspect that the line `x_train_tf = vectorizer.fit_transform(str(x_train).split('\n')).toarray()` is not doing what you think it does. Try to decompose the `str(x_train).split('\n')` part.